# Jquery: How to pass in .next or .prev as a function variable?

Tags: jquery, function, variables

In my code below, I want to be able to pass in prev or next.
I basically just want to know how to make pn into a variable in my function(I tried below but its wrong), so i can do this:

```
doSlide($('UL li:last'), 0, next)
```

or

```
doSlide($('UL li:last'), 15, prev)
```

function:

```
function doSlide(current, px, pn) {
    $(current).animate({
        right: px
    },200);
    setTimeout(function(){
            doSlide($(current)."+ pn +"('li'), px);           
    },45);
}
```

Comment: What is "next" and "prev"? Are those variables, or are you trying to pass in an element?

Comment: see the function posted above, im passing those in to choose whether to select the .prev('li'), or the .next('li') based on mouseover/out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd send the functions as strings like this:

```
doSlide($('UL li:last'), 15, "next")
```

or

```
doSlide($('UL li:last'), 15, "prev")
```

And the function would be:

```
function doSlide(current, px, pn) {
    $(current).animate({
        right: px
    },200);
    setTimeout(function(){
            doSlide($(current)[pn]('li'), px);           
    },45);
}
```

Try it. It works.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Further to your code and @Edgar Villegas Alvarado's answer, the problem is that you never check if there's anything returned by `.next()` or `.prev()`, therefore your recursion will never end, it will keep firing your function on empty jQuery objects every 45ms.

Use this:

```
function doSlide(current, px, pn) {
    $(current).animate({
        right: px
    },200);

    var $next = $(current)[pn]('li');
    if($next.length){
        setTimeout(function(){
            doSlide($next, px);           
        },45);
    }
}

doSlide($('ul li:first'), 15, "next");

// or

doSlide($('ul li:last'), 15, "prev");
```